# Confused by loaded data of scipy.io.loadmat()

Tags: python, matlab

I'm trying to load a .mat eye-tracking database from [this page](http://antoinecoutrot.magix.net/public/databases.html). The link of the database is [here](http://antoinecoutrot.magix.net/public/assets/coutrot_database1.mat)

After loading using `scipy.io.loadmat()` function, I found it's hard to understand the loaded data. I don't understand how it corresponds to the original data.

First, the data contains nested numpy arrays, which is not useful because I can't even access the shape. Second, if opening the database by Matlab, I could see the fields I need. But when it was loaded in Python, I can't see how the nested arrays correspond to those fields.

Can someone share an advice on my issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer could be referred to the documentation of this function.

> simplify_cells:
> False, optional. If True, return a simplified dict
> structure (which is useful if the mat file contains cell arrays). Note
> that this only affects the structure of the result and not its
> contents (which is identical for both output structures). If True,
> this automatically sets struct_as_record to False and squeeze_me to
> True, which is required to simplify cells.

So, simply pass `simplify_cells = True`, you would get a dict with clear information.